# Typescript - How to use generics to define a function that returns indexable properties of an object?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am having trouble writing the correct types for a simple function.

I want to create a function that when given a key (`keyof any`) or callback will return another function. This function takes in some data and returns another key.

In other words both `toKey('propertyName')` and `toKey(value => value.propertyName)` would return the function `value => value.propertyName`. When called, the function would return the given value of said property only if the value is a `string`, `number` or `symbol` type.

Here's an example:

```js
function toKey(keyIdentity) { /* snippet */ }

interface IPerson {
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string,
    age: number,
    emails: string[]
};

const getKey1 = toKey((person: IPerson) => person.emails[0]);
const getKey2 = toKey('firstName');
const getKey3 = toKey('emails');

const person: IPerson = {
    firstName: 'Craig',
    lastName: 'Lipton',
    age: 46,
    emails: [
        '<email-1>',
        '<email-2>'
    ]
};

getKey1(person); // returns "<email-1>";
getKey2(person); // returns "Craig";
getKey3(person); // not allowed;
```

I've attempted to use generics and overloads to achieve the correct typing but it gets complicated very quickly.

```js
function toKey(key?: null): () => void;
function toKey<K extends keyof any>(key: K): <U extends keyof any>(item: Record<K, U>) => U;
function toKey<T extends (...args: any[]) => keyof any>(key: T): T;
function toKey(key: any): any {
    if (isNil(key)) {
        return noop;
    }

    return isFunction(key) ? key : (value: T) => value[key];
}
```

Is there any simpler way to write this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be explicit in your types, the built-in `PropertyKey` type can be used:

```
// type PropertyKey = string | number | symbol

function toKey<K extends PropertyKey>(key: K): 
  <T extends Record<K, PropertyKey>>(t: T) => PropertyKey
function toKey<T>(fn: (t: T) => PropertyKey): (t: T) => PropertyKey
function toKey(key: PropertyKey | ((t: Record<PropertyKey, PropertyKey>) => PropertyKey)) {...}
```

Test it:

```
toKey((person: IPerson) => person.emails[0])(person); // "<email-1>";
toKey('firstName')(person); // "Craig";
toKey('emails')(person); // error, emails prop is not string | number | symbol
toKey('lastName')({ firstName: "Lui" }); // error, object passed in has no key "lastName"
```

[Code sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=8&ssc=47&pln=8&pc=48#code/PTAECMFcEsBsBcC00B2p4E8AOBTUAFAJwHtdDMBpHDUAXlAGd5DUBzUAH1BUgFtwchTowz9isAFAhQAQQYM+bUBmKRQAQ1gB3dRgagdKeOmKhCOeJEJpiKPMQBmG8MQBueLC17R40dwwkHSBQAY19bEyoMAB4KUBwAD3gcFAATfSJSQUpqAD4ACgBragAuUAoASjLogBV4pJT00AAlHBDiQlTYgBoCEjIcjFyC+DKairpcvqzyDCjA4LDoCPhiKNqChxQy-NHQccnpgbnqKtBdsYnaKczj+aDQ8LRVqKLSo+yTmi58i5a2jpdW6fKK9YGzKK5K43fog04TADeElAKLMFisaD+rXanWi4MGYNhELy0ORqPJmFwjlAxRotHpoAARA8lrZGaAAPw06i7DT6bGAvFEgkfYlDCpk8lS0BleAAbVpfMYzCUXB4-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)

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about the `PropertyKey`! That makes things a lot more readable! Thanks.

Comment: @Robert that's because I don't see it mention anywhere in official doc as of this date. Only source I can find it mention is [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/e44142048305d42ec4fc753457aa561f8e247e4f/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L90)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this,

```
function toKey<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T>(key: K): (v: T) => T[K];
```

```
const getKey3 = toKey<IPerson>('emails');
const getKey3 = toKey<IPerson,"emails">('emails');
```

[Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFOBpApgTwBQGssD8AXImCADbkCUJ2ViAvAHyIBucMAJgNwBQokWAmRosAHlSJ0ADyjownAM6J8mOMEQBDMJiZ4sJVDURiAqlNnylKrOq069MOQFsSAJXQQ4AJ04SANIimTPTMQXwC0PBIKBiYYgAqFnIKytgAdJma3gDmiiTamADaALqhLKp2hXqqJAnGCRHgUcKx4gmBkjIp1pUaSQw2av01BohGtKx15YgJRaglTYLRInH6mAU6xoWIAN68iIeI3uhQIN5IZJR8AL68vDBgct7AmhDoiACSAAro3orCfZHRDAGD-KAAOU0znQJEUUG8jxy-gOR3ImnhUJhcIRSJRwM0OVhpBAzgARn98Ud0M5NDByPlEPDEWAcqVeDc+LwvGB4YgiVA4gBGRirLDYbAABz+ALAJB+MoQM2l-wQ6RpdIZRQADGU+Dy+QK4gAmUVtHAAclB4Kx6AtVH1CENpziAGYzaJ4grVWBAgAiDX0xR+vQWwMM+1cg1QRAq2Xy34+0VAo7WzHQ4kWgDC3jpOQtVMO6PT2MQFoAMjBJSgwAXUYdCcSACwANkLUlpQZIRXrwLLYnDAFohUw632jhaB53yIPjaPeyUOVyjVghVLFWAHYgAPTb46nc68xB+qea4dMP18FeYY3rn1b3f7s4XZR+nN5y+8a+uu+yh97sA4BjTRKDgAB3dAeCAA)

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply! Yeah, this is alright, but then I would need to specify the type to use it.

It would be good if I could still use it like normal javascript (i.e. `toKey('emails')`).