# What is the Built-in Object Key type called?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I remember previously using a built in type that is the union of all possible object keys, and it was name `objectKey` or something similar.

For example:

```
type objectKey = string | number | symbol
```

However, I can’t remember the specific name now. Does anyone know what it is named?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript - How to use generics to define a function that returns indexable properties of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59640569/typescript-how-to-use-generics-to-define-a-function-that-returns-indexable-pro). Also keep in mind this might be overly wide in some (most?) situations as objects actually only have 'string' or 'symbol' keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called [`PropertyKey`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L107).

```
declare type PropertyKey = string | number | symbol;
```